# How to convert Dictionary<> to Hashtable in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I see many question/answers about how to convert a Hashtable to a Dictionary, but how can I convert a Dictionary to a Hashtable?

Comment: And why would you need that? A Hashtable is very specific in that a value computed on the key produces the location of the value... and a dictionary is just a straight (key, value) collection. Why would you want to convert a dictionary to a hashtable?

Comment: At the simplest level, I am lazy. The object that is of type `Hashtable` is used in a lot of places.

Comment: That in itself is not a reason to use it. Dictionaries and Hashtables are different beasts that are used under different circumstances. You know, a List<int> is also used in a lot of places... So why not use that? :-s

Comment: @RoyDictus: Dictionary is just a generic Hashtable. It serves the same purpose.

Comment: @RoyDictus It is a reason to use it if I do not feel like going through all the code to make things work with a Dictionary.

Comment: Ah now I get it, sorry. I didn't know you were a hobbyist. Sorry again.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The easiest way is using constructor of Hashtable:

```
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<object, object>();
        //... fill the dictionary
        var hashtable = new Hashtable(dictionary);
```

Answer (score 8):

```
Dictionary<int, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>
   {
      {1,"One"},
      {2,"Two"}
   };
Hashtable hashtable = new Hashtable(dictionary);
```

Try this

Answer (score 5):

Seems pretty rare to want to do, but at the simplest:

```
var hash = new Hashtable();
foreach(var pair in dictionary) {
    hash.Add(pair.Key,pair.Value);
}
```

(assuming no unusual "implements typed equality check but not untyped equality check" etc)

Comment: Now just include this in a `ToHashTable` extension method and voila!

Comment: There's even a [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdkta2sx.aspx) that does the same thing.

Comment: This is what I was thinking of doing. Was wondering if there was a not so obvious way to do it. However, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You might want to consider using the `Hashtable` constructor overload that takes an `IEqualityComparer` parameter:

```
var hashtable = new Hashtable(dictionary, (IEqualityComparer) dictionary.Comparer);
```

In this way, your Hashtable uses the same `Comparer` as the dictionary.  For example, if your dictionary used a case-insensitive string key, you might want your `Hashtable` to be case-insensitive too.  E.g.:

```
var d = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
d.Add("a", "a");
d.Add("b", "b");

bool found;
found = d.ContainsKey("A"); // true

var hashtable1 = new Hashtable(d);
var hashtable2 = new Hashtable(d, (IEqualityComparer) d.Comparer);

found = hashtable1["A"] != null; // false - by default it's case-sensitive

found = hashtable2["A"] != null; // true - uses same comparer as the original dictionary
```