# PowerShell convert dictionary to hashtable

Tags: powershell, dictionary, hash, hashtable

I have a runbook running on Azure. I get a data type **System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]**, but I need convert it to **System.Collections.Hashtable**.

I find a [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927779/how-to-convert-dictionary-to-hashtable-in-c) using C#, but how can I do it with Power Shell?

In other words, in my scenario, I need convert dictionary type to hashtable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C# answer in PowerShell is simply:

```
Write-Host "....dictionary"
$d = [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]]::new()  # `
$d.Add("one", "111")
$d.Add("two", "222")
Write-Host "$d"
$d | ft

Write-Host "....hashtable"
$h = [System.Collections.Hashtable]::new($d)
Write-Host "$h"
$h | ft
```

Answer (score 9):

To complement [Kory Gill's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48679398/45375) with a more PowerShell-idiomatic solution:

- PowerShell's type accelerator for `[System.Collections.Hashtable]` is `[hashtable]`
- PowerShell allows you to use *cast syntax* if the cast's type has a single-argument constructor of the RHS's type or of an interface implemented by it.

Therefore, you can **cast directly to `[hashtable]`** in this case.<sup>[1]</sup>

```
# Create a sample dictionary (using PSv5+ syntax; in PSv4-, use New-Object)
($dict = [Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string, string]]::new()).Add('foo', 'bar')

# Cast the generic dictionary directly to a hashtable.
# (Assign the result to a variable as needed, e.g. 
#   $hash = [hastable] $dict
#   [hashtable] $hash = $dict # with type constraint (variable type locked in)
# )
[hashtable] $dict
```

Note that *nested* generic dictionaries are *not* converted. That is, the input dictionary's *values* are retained as-is, even if they happen to be generic dictionaries too.

---

<sup>[1] A generic dictionary implements the `IDictionary` interface (among others), and `[hashtable]` has a [`public Hashtable (System.Collections.IDictionary d)` constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Collections_Hashtable__ctor_System_Collections_IDictionary_)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the Dictionary to a hashtable by predefining the variable type.

```
[hastable]$var = $var
```